# Why does casting a raw pointer to a unique_ptr not delete the original?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I am trying to understand unique_ptr, but they have me a bit stumped.
Consider the following code:

```
PartClass * part= new PartClass;

//The OwnerClass is a composite that excpects a unique_ptr
OwnerClass * owner = new OwnerClass( unique_ptr<PartClass>( part );
```

After the second line of code I would expect the original pointer - part - to have been deleted. After all, as soon as you have a unique_ptr it creates a lot of fuss, needing to be moved, etc. So why does the compiler allow a raw pointer to still access the part-object? Doesn't it violate the whole concept of unique_ptr?

Comment: `part` won't be deleted because ownership will be moved into `OwnerClass`, assuming that `OwnerClass` stores it somewhere. Is that what you're confused about?

Comment: "So why does the compiler allow a raw pointer to still access the part-object? Doesn't it violate the whole concept of unique_ptr?" it's a free world(more like compiler), you can `delete 42;` if you like, the compiler does not ask your intentions, and if you want to divide by zero he won't stop you, it's up to you to decide if you want to use the raw pointer or the correct `unique_ptr`, there is no `laws` here, sometimes you might want to do a hack and use raw..

Comment: you seem to have a big misunderstanding with pointer, if `unique_ptr` would delete `part`, how will he use it? And if you are talking about the `part` it self and not it's referenced content, then it's allocated on the stack for this scope, and will be deleted when you leave the scope.

Comment: There may be many valid reasons for holding on to the symbol 'part'.  If it is your desire you can 'enforce' that only the unique_ptr exists and simply use an anonymous symbol to create it,  i.e. new OwnerClass ( unique_ptr<PartClass>(new PartClass)).

Comment: Pete (see his answer) had it right. My question was really, why the raw pointer is not set to a null pointer. The move semantics do that, but obviously

Comment: (continuation - sorry I'm new here, and got interrupted.)
... obviously they are not enforced on a raw pointer. I assumed that ownership also meant the exclusive right to access the memory of the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for the same reason that you can explicitly give out the pointer. For example:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> value = std::make_unique<int>(1);
int* pValue = value.get();
```

While `pValue` can access the memory it **does not own it** and should not delete the memory. In your example the ownership has been transferred while there happens to be a raw pointer that still points the the resource, which is fine.

Comment: Thank you James - that clarified the issue. I expected too much of a unique_ptr, namely exclusive access and that is obviously not the case.

Comment: @schulefant What it guarantees is _exclusive ownership_.

Answer (score 1):

A `unique_ptr` is just another class from the compiler standpoint. As it stands, one of its ctors accepts a raw pointer. It's dtor will release the memory via passed in raw pointer (typically `free`).

The fact your variable part points to the same memory location does not change any of the `unique_ptr` behaviour. In this context that is just another local object.

The fact you do hold a raw pointer to the same memory managed via `unique_ptr` (order does not matter) may potentially lead to a double free, and undefined behaviour (hopefully a crash). I'd recommend passing `new PartClass` directly to `unique_ptr` initialization.

Answer (score 1):

By passing `part` to the `unique_ptr` you passed across ownership of the pointer to `unique_ptr`.

Yes, you've still got a raw pointer, but as you've given ownership to the smart pointer you should consider it off limits. You certainly don't want to be deleting it.

Answer (score 1):

The `PartClass` object still exists, and that's what was intended, so it absolutely should not be deleted. The question is really why isn't `part` set to a null pointer, and that's because it's up to you to manage such things. The pointer is valid, and you can use it if you want to. If you don't want to use it, don't keep it around.

Comment: Thank you Pete - you got it right - my question was really, why part is not set to null